# ToString with CultureInfo gives two different formats

Tags: .net, date, format

This:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nb-NO"))
```

gives me different formats in Linqpad and Visual Studio-immediate window.
Linqpad returns 18.01.2018 15:56:15
Visual studio gives me 18.01.2018 15.56.15 (Colons are missing)

Linqpad version 5.26.01

My guess is this is caused by different .dlls beeing used. What's the best way to check this ?

Comment: @Tim line above: "gives me different formats in Linqpad and Visual Studio-immediate window" - seems clear to me

Comment: I get `19.01.2018 09:54:49` in both